# Question about generalized DeMorgan's Laws

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to simplify $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{R} \setminus [-\frac{1}{n},1+\frac{1}{n})$ using DeMorgan's Laws, and trying to prove that the two resulting sets are equal $\textit{without}$ using DeMorgan's Laws (so no proof by induction basically). This is what I have:

"Using DeMorgan's law, we have that $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{R} \setminus [-\frac{1}{n},1+\frac{1}{n})=\mathbb{R} \setminus (\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}[-\frac{1}{n},1+\frac{1}{n}))=\mathbb{R} \setminus [0,1)=(-\infty,0)\cup[1,\infty).$
We will now give a formal proof of the fact that $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{R} \setminus [-\frac{1}{n},1+\frac{1}{n})=\mathbb{R} \setminus (\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}[-\frac{1}{n},1+\frac{1}{n}))$.
$(\subseteq)$ Suppose that $x \in \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{R} \setminus [-\frac{1}{n},1+\frac{1}{n})$.
Then by definition, $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x \notin [-\frac{1}{n},1+\frac{1}{n})$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
This implies that $x \notin \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}[-\frac{1}{n},1+\frac{1}{n})$.
This then gives us that $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus (\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}[-\frac{1}{n},1+\frac{1}{n}))$.
Thus, $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{R} \setminus [-\frac{1}{n},1+\frac{1}{n})) \subseteq \mathbb{R} \setminus (\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}[-\frac{1}{n},1+\frac{1}{n}))$.
$(\supseteq)$ Now suppose that $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus (\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}[-\frac{1}{n},1+\frac{1}{n}))$.
Then $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x \notin \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}[-\frac{1}{n},1+\frac{1}{n})$.
Since $x \notin \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}[-\frac{1}{n},1+\frac{1}{n})$, then $x \notin [-\frac{1}{n},1+\frac{1}{n})$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
This implies that $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus [-\frac{1}{n},1+\frac{1}{n})$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
Thus, $x \in \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{R} \setminus [-\frac{1}{n},1+\frac{1}{n})$.
Therefore, we have that $\mathbb{R} \setminus (\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}[-\frac{1}{n},1+\frac{1}{n})) \subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{R} \setminus [-\frac{1}{n},1+\frac{1}{n})$
And so, we obtain that $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{R} \setminus [-\frac{1}{n},1+\frac{1}{n})=\mathbb{R} \setminus (\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}[-\frac{1}{n},1+\frac{1}{n}))$, as was to be shown."

How does this look? Any issues?

Comment: Proof looks fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is fine, but your original calculation using the De Morgan law isn’t quite right:

$$\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\left[-\frac1n,1+\frac1n\right)=[0,1]\,,$$

not $[0,1)$: $1\in\left[-\frac1n,1+\frac1n\right)$ for every $n\in\Bbb Z^+$.

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Comment: @bzoll213: You’re welcome!